# Getting an element by id in angular brackets

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to be able to set the width of a canvas to that of its parent div. However, this has to be done manually because using the CSS tags width/height just stenches the canvas instead of expanding it.

To get the size of a div programatically I would have done the following: `document.getElementById('canvasParent').getBoundingClientRect().width`. However, it seems that `document` is not defined within `{{ }}` and this method does not work. Does anyone know how I would be able to get this within angle brackets.

Edit - Example:

```
<div class="col-md-9" id="canvasParent" style="position: relative">
    <canvas id="subpartCanvas" style="position: absolute; z-index:1024"></canvas>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <label class="btn btn-default" ng-repeat="v in col" ng-mouseover="hoverSubPart($index)">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This would be tied in with a painting part, that will paint a line between label pairs when hovering over them with a mouse.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you show us the context?

Comment: Done, but also the canvas does not seem to render when provided a height/width within {{}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to get the document on view you have to expose it on scope (not a good idea but it will work)

on ur controller

```
$scope.document = $document;
```

note: $document should be injected

best way to do calculation on controller and set a scope variable to use on view.

Another suggestion try css and give width in vw & vh unit.

Like width : 100vw;

Comment: This sadly will not work since from further testing the following does not work: `<canvas width="{{100}}" height="{{100}}"></canvas>`